# What is the meaning of "require: ^"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What does the ^ mean under require in this angular directive?
I found this snippet and trying to figure out what it's saying.

```
.directive('accordionGroupHeading', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,  
        template: '',       
        replace: true,
        require: '^accordingGroup',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, accessibleAccordionGroupCtrl, transclude) {

            accessibleAccordionGroupCtrl.setHeading(transclude(scope, function() {}));
        }
    };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `require` in this is not about require js it is actually saying that this directive requires a parent of type `accordingGroup`

take a look at the angular documentation for more info

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> The ^^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on its parents. (A ^ prefix would make the directive look for the controller on its own element or its parents; without any prefix, the directive would look on its own element only.)

So basically you will have an error if your directive won't find the controller. Using require, you will be able to get access to the controller from the `link` method of directive.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {}
```